# How do I add a row into a mysql stored procedure resultset?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, resultset, temporary-objects

I´m working in an application that creates a simulated population database. I´m trying to write a stored procedure that creates a temporary table internally, add rows and then fetch this resultset as procedure result .

I wrote a basic code that only add 3 lines to a temp table for a test, but still not working

[EDITED]: phpmyadmin return ad non-specific compilation error #1064 you have an error in yor sql statement sintax....

[EDITED2]:
I haven´t found exactly what error is, but changing the "create termaporary table" line to a "create temporary table OUT_TEMP **ENGINE=MEMORY as (Select * from OTHER_TABLE where 1=2)**" it works.

see the code below:

```
DELIMITER//
create procedure GERA_POPULACAO(IN stDESCRICAO VARCHAR, IN stUSUARIO 
                                 VARCHAR, IN iID_ESPECIE int, 
                                 IN iNUM_INDIVIDUOS INT)
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OUT_TEMP( ID_INDIVIDUO int, ID_RACA int, 
                                 ID_CARACTERISTICA int, 
                                 VR_CARACTERISTICA int);

    insert into OUT_TEMP values(1,1,1,1);
    insert into OUT_TEMP values(1,1,1,2);
    insert into OUT_TEMP values(1,1,1,3);

    SELECT * from OUT_TEMP;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

appreciate any help

Comment: How is it not working? More specifics is good.

Comment: phpmyadmin return ad non-specific compilation error #1064 you have an error in yor sql statement sintax....

Comment: @TarcisoJunior Does the error message say where in the statement the syntax error is?

Comment: after the "create temporary table" command

Comment: I haven´t found exactly what error is, but changing the "create termaporary table" line to a "create temporary table OUT_TEMP ENGINE=MEMORY as (Select * from OTHER_TABLE where 1=2)" it works.